# How do I stop my Xamarin.UITest from running Tests twice?

Tags: c#, xamarin, ui-testing, xamarin.uitest

I am writing some `UITests` using the `Xamarin.UITest` library. but every test I run always runs twice regardless of whether it has passed or failed?

My app configuration looks like this:

```
app = ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile(PathToAPK).WaitTimes(new WaitTimes()).EnableLocalScreenshots().StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear);
```

and all my test classes are marked with the following attributes:

```
[TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
[TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
```

I run the test on Android and it will run twice on Android regardless of whether it has passed or failed.

How do I stop this? / What is causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so I found the problem here.

all my `TestClasses` inherited from my own `UITestBase`. I had declarated `UITestBase` with the `TestFixture` attributes. and I had also declarated my `TestClasses` with the same attribute. which resulted in this:

**Test Class**

```
[TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
[TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
class TestClass : UITestBase
{

}
```

**Base class**

```
[TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
[TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
class UITestBase
{
}
```

Therefore ended up with my tests all running twice

Comment: I can't believe I did this too. I was tearing my hair out! Thank you! ;)